# Display Json file in random order

Tags: php, json

I like to fill the table with data in another order than the file content.

The file have data about house for sale. The Json file returned from the server has the order so the lovest "days for sale"  come first. This make my table ordered by "days for sale" I would like to put the order in another way so the house come in a mixed order (days for sale) see

http://bryllupfoto.com/bachbolig/demo.php

Any idea how to solve this ?

Nb i will keep the same order displayed for one week. Then reorder again for one week, so the visitor not get the house in new order for every time he visit the page.

```
<?php   
$data = file_get_contents("http://xxx/service/v20/list?orgKey=xxxxxxx");  
$data = json_decode($data, true);  
foreach($data as $row)  
{  
   if ($row["status"] == 'ACTIVE' && $row["reserved"] <> true) {
   echo '<td align="left">days displayed </td>
         <td align="right">'.$row["daysForSale"].' </td>
         </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to shuffle the $data array using the function proposed in the second user post under the [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) documentation, to keep the correct array keys:

```
<?php
function shuffle_assoc($list) {
  if (!is_array($list)) return $list;
  $keys = array_keys($list);
  shuffle($keys);
  $random = array();
  foreach ($keys as $key)
     $random[$key] = $list[$key];
  return $random;
  }
?>
```

Then you can save the shuffled $data array in a cache with a TTL of 1 week. Here is a good tutorial about different caches available in PHP and how to use them:

http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2014/01/26/getting-started-with-caching-in-php/

I hope this helps you.